# JavaFX WebEngine Executing Javascript Sequentially To Do Actions on the Website

Tags: java, javafx-8

I want to use [JavaFX WebEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) in such a way that I can execute Javascript code in order to fill one form and click submit button on the website I opened. I was using ChromeDriver but I didn't like certain aspects of it, WebView fits better for my needs, but as far as I researched, the only way to make sure a page is loaded is to add a state listener to WebEngine and when it's SUCCEEDED, make operations on webpage. However, when I execute Javascript and submit a form, a new webpage opens so it's SUCCEEDED for the second time (first time, opens webpage that contains the form) and it executes the same form-filling code in listener. I want to execute other Javascript code after submitting the form but I couldn't find a good way to do that. In ChromeDriver, I could simply wait for certain amount of time, but with WebView case, because it executes in UI thread, I can't do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if that's what you mean. `SUCCEEDED` is just a information about state of engine, to be more accurate you should check other parameters, for instance: If you want to handle different pages inside one listener, you can use location-based (currently loaded url) verification.

```
WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue != State.SUCCEEDED) {
        return;
    }

    String location = engine.getLocation();

    if (location.contains("page1")) {
        // Do something
        return;
    }

    if (location.contains("page2")) {
        // Do something
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Unhandled location: " + location);
});
```

Comment: Generally, websites I'm going to use are web applications, so their URLs don't change page to page.

Comment: Location-based solution is just an example. If your page properties do not change, you can try to get some information from loaded page by calling a javascript and operate on returned value.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to work with JavaScript in WebEngine so I can also recommend you to add web console listener by WebConsoleListener.setDefaultListener before you execute your script to get useful info.